# How to save favourites into Android Preferences

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I would like to use Preferences to store favourite words from my dictionary app. I know it is not wise doing so (as a few of you have advised) but currently using Preferences seems to be the best choice for me.

However, I have a problem which is that the app does not save favourite words although everything appears normal (I mean no errors found). Here below is my code:

```
//Saving to favourites
    btnAddFavourite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddFavourite);
    btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (prefs.getBoolean("saveFavourite", true) && mWordFavourite != null && mWordFavourite.size() >= 1)
                {
                    saveFavouriteToPreferences();
                    StringBuilder sbFavourite = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String item : mWordFavourite)
                    {
                        sbFavourite.append(item);
                        sbFavourite.append(",");
                    }

                    String strFavourite = sbFavourite.substring(0, sbFavourite.length()-1);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("favourite", strFavourite);
                    editor.commit();
                    //Log.i(CONTENT_TAG,"Favourite = " + strFavourite);
                    Log.i(CONTENT_TAG,"Favourite saved!");
                }

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ContentView.this, R.string.messageWordAddedToFarvourite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

            private void saveFavouriteToPreferences() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

//Loading favourites
    btnAddFavourite.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {         

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            if (prefs.getBoolean("saveFavourite", true))
            {
                String strFavourite = prefs.getString("favourite", "");
                Log.i(CONTENT_TAG, "Favourite loaded");
                if (strFavourite != null && !strFavourite.equals(""))
                {
                    mWordFavourite = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strFavourite.split(",")));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mWordFavourite == null)
                    {
                        mWordFavourite = new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mWordFavourite.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (mWordFavourite == null)
                {
                    mWordFavourite = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                else
                {
                    mWordFavourite.clear();
                }
            }

            // Open the favourite Activity, which in turn will fetch the saved favourites, to show them.
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavouriteView.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);  

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I think Favourite is loaded but saved because when I long-click on the Favourite button LogCat shows "Favourite loaded". Here is the log:

```
11-15 10:26:40.849: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent {cmp=myapp.dict/.HistoryView }
11-15 10:26:40.899: I/[Dict - Content](283): History saved!
11-15 10:26:40.979: I/[Dict - HistoryView](283): History loaded
11-15 10:26:40.989: D/[Dict - HistoryView](283): mWordHistory = 11
11-15 10:26:40.989: I/[Dict - HistoryView](283): item = english_mylang::8::"B" licence
...
11-15 10:26:41.508: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity myapp.dict/.HistoryView: 607 ms (total 607 ms)
11-15 10:26:44.388: W/KeyCharacterMap(283): No keyboard for id 0
11-15 10:26:44.388: W/KeyCharacterMap(283): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-15 10:26:44.448: I/[Dict - Content](283): resultCode = 0
11-15 10:26:44.458: D/dalvikvm(59): GREF has increased to 301
11-15 10:26:54.454: I/[Dict - Content](283): Favourite loaded
11-15 10:26:54.458: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=viettien.kadict/.FavouriteView }
11-15 10:26:54.498: I/[Dict - Content](283): History saved!
11-15 10:26:54.548: I/[Dict - FavouriteView](283): Favourite loaded
11-15 10:26:54.548: D/[Dict - FavouriteView](283): mWordFavourite = 0
11-15 10:26:54.949: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity myapp.dict/.FavouriteView: 448 ms (total 448 ms)
```

**So my questions are:**

1. What have I done wrong?
2. How can I improve the code?

---

***UPDATE:***

As Maneesh and Alan Moore showed, there is a problem with the **"saveFavourite" (boolean value)**. I now wonder if there are any ways to code in order to save Favourites right after **onClick**. I mean:

```
//Saving to favourites
btnAddFavourite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddFavourite);
btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        **//Is it possible to code to save Favourites at this stage?** 

            if (prefs.getBoolean("saveFavourite", true) && mWordFavourite != null && mWordFavourite.size() >= 1)
            {
                saveFavouriteToPreferences();
                StringBuilder sbFavourite = new StringBuilder();
                for (String item : mWordFavourite)
                {
                    sbFavourite.append(item);
                    sbFavourite.append(",");
                }

                String strFavourite = sbFavourite.substring(0, sbFavourite.length()-1);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("favourite", strFavourite);
                editor.commit();
                //Log.i(CONTENT_TAG,"Favourite = " + strFavourite);
                Log.i(CONTENT_TAG,"Favourite saved!");
            }

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ContentView.this, R.string.messageWordAddedToFarvourite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        private void saveFavouriteToPreferences() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you sure that you are saving "saveFavourite" (boolean value) along with favourites. I mean before commiting preferences?

Comment: Not clear on where you set the prefs boolean saveFavorite flag?

Comment: Can you make it a little clearer to me?

Comment: @Alan Moore: I have this in my main dict class:public void loadPreferences()
 {
  boolean found = false;

  mSaveHistory = prefs.getBoolean("saveHistory", true);
  mSaveFavourite = prefs.getBoolean("saveFavourite", true);
  
  String savedDB = prefs.getString("defaultDictionary", ""); //Default dictionary is the first dictionary in the list
  String savedDBPath = prefs.getString("defaultDictionaryPath", ""); //Default dictionary is the first dictionary in the list
  if (savedDB.trim().equals("") || savedDBPath.trim().equals(""))

Comment: Its not clear to me that your favorite is actually getting saved, I don't see it in your log either.

Comment: @Alan Moore: I don't think so, either but don't know how to save it. I updated my question to reflect this problem. How should I do to save favourite now? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preference seems to be a not good choice for your need because
1)Its not advised to store large data in preferences.
2)If you go to settings->your application_>clear data in your device all data stored in preferences will be lost
Why dont you use sqlite db instead?

Comment: If you use Clear Data in settings, it will delete your SQLite database too, I believe

Comment: upvote, sqlLite is a good choice here. If users go into the app settings and clear local data, its their own fault, they know what they're getting up to.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would borrow heavily from the Searchable Dictionary sample app -- since it also searches a dictionary of words so a lot of the functionality is built in there:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Its hard to debug your code because so many things seem to be missing which might be causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, but sample Searchable Dictionary does not include History and Favourite functions.